# Is it possible to work with HTTParty request results as an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, json, httparty

I wonder if it possible to work with [HTTParty](http://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) request results as an object.

Currently I use string keys to access to values of result: `result["imageurl"]` or `result["address"]["street"]`

If i were in JavaScript I could simply use: `result.imageurl` or `result.address.street`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `Mash` class of the [hashie](http://github.com/intridea/hashie) gem.

```
tweet = Hashie::Mash.new(
  HTTParty.get("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json").first
)
tweet.user.screen_name
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote [this helper class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576557/automatically-map-json-objects-into-instance-variables-in-ruby/3577065#3577065) a few days ago:

```
class ObjectifiedHash

    def initialize hash
        @data = hash.inject({}) do |data, (key,value)|  
            value = ObjectifiedHash.new value if value.kind_of? Hash
            data[key.to_s] = value
            data
        end
    end

    def method_missing key
        if @data.key? key.to_s
            @data[key.to_s]
        else
            nil
        end
    end

end
```

Usage example:

```
ojson = ObjectifiedHash.new(HTTParty.get('http://api.dribbble.com/players/simplebits'))
ojson.shots_counts # => 150
```